# Get not the latest imagery of maps

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps, yandex-maps

Is there any possibility to get not the latest imagery for google/bing/yandex maps?
For example, I'd like to show on my website imagery for the 2005 year. 
I couldn't find this methods in APIs.

Thank you,
Dmitry.

Comment: Well, unfortunately you can't

Comment: @psousa see my answer below

Comment: I answered based on my knowledge of Bing Maps. Didn't notice you had tagged the question with other map providers, which I'm not as familiar. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81794/how-to-retrieve-historical-imagery-from-web-mapping-services/ :

"This may not be the exact answer, but may help you on your journey. Take a look at this Article on How to View Historical Satellite Imagery in Google Earth or Explore Google Earth's Historical Imagery.

Google Maps API can be used in 'Earth' mode see 'Time Machine' https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=earth#time_and_historical_imagery_ui Enable then enter a YEAR date (2005)."

Answer (score 2):

Bing Maps does not make historical imagery available.