# Google Satellite Image Date in gmaps for iOS

Tags: ios, image, google-maps, date, satellite

Does Google have a service that can make me able to access older satellite images using gmaps api for iOS?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. Looked around the community for a while and found a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890070/get-not-the-latest-imagery-of-maps) that is pretty much asking for what you are aiming for. The selected answer has a [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81794/how-to-retrieve-historical-imagery-from-web-mapping-services), which is also not a clear answer. I also tried the sample link (http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=earth#time_and_historical_imagery_ui) provided in the comments but it doesn't seem to be working anymore.

I also managed to find this open [feature request on Historical Satellite imagery](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7950) . You can support it if you want.